# Why does the jQuery library expose DOM elements?

Tags: jquery, api-design

**This is a question about the *design* of the jQuery API, not specifics of usage.**

Why is a jQuery object a collection of DOM elements and not a collection of jQuery objects?

Working with only jQuery objects would allow all DOM manipulation to be done the same way throughout your code. It seems that most usage patterns immediately convert the DOM element into a jQuery object anyway. As I understand it, many DOM-element-to-jQuery-object conversions are expected, that's why they chose a shorthand `$` function.

Why do it this way? Why not assume we want to manipulate the DOM through jQuery and avoid explicit conversions everywhere?

Comment: Not sure where you're getting your information. jQuery returns a jQuery object that contains a collection of DOM nodes. The object returned is an instance of `jQuery`.

Comment: @zzzzBov Presumably he's talking about things like `$.fn.each`, which pass the DOM element.

Comment: `$(this)[0]` still holds the original JavaScript structure when asked for. This is a very strong combination to mix raw JavaScript with jQuery's functionality.

Comment: @ everyone voting up the first comment.  the OP is not talking about the jQuery function.

Comment: @zzzzBov I was afraid people would confuse my use of 'jQuery' with the `jQuery` function. Changing the title.

Comment: @treydavis, my comment still stands, `.children()` returns a jQuery object, which contains references to DOM elements. The jQuery library uses vector programming to affect all elements within a set. This has the added advantage of continuing to work even when the set is empty.

Comment: Might i suggest replacing `.children()` with a method that better demonstrates what you're asking? such as `.filter`? or am I still missing what you are asking.

Comment: @zzzzBov I see my error. My inexperience with jQuery is showing. I'm still curious about the core of my question though. Why didn't the writers of jQuery choose insulate the user from the DOM? I'll update the question to correct/clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be inefficient to create a jquery object when one isn't needed. For example:

```
$("a").each(function(){
    console.log(this.href);
});
```

since the href is always available as a property of the DOMElement, it would be a waste to turn that into a jQuery object and use `.attr`.

For jQuery to make each one a jQuery object, it would have to make a new jQuery object for each element it iterates over, which is a waste if you don't need it to be a jQuery object. The same thought process can be applied to event handlers, the filter method, and any other method that iterates over elements.

Comment: Is there any reason other than unnecessary overhead? Is the conversion really that expensive, especially for modern browsers?

Comment: There is a bit of overhead involved, http://jsperf.com/jquery-eq-vs-get it's much faster to get the dom element than a jQuery object containing the dom element when starting from a jQuery object.

Comment: I see. Several times faster. So jQuery is designed for DOM selection and manipulating several elements at once. For working with individual elements, use the DOMElement directly.

Comment: Correct, it's usually Much faster to work with the DOMElement directly, Only resort to using jQuery when it either makes the code more convenient, readable, maintainable, and/or cross-browser.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery objects allows you to use a wide range of usefull jQuery functions on any Dom element you could reach thanks to Dom traversal functions.
You still have the possibility to get the original Dom element whatever the related jQuery object you are manipulating.